# Auto Join using (JoinByOne , JoinByArray)

Tags: apostrophe-cms

Usually , user need to manually choose which pieces/pages that needed to join. For Example : 
[image]

Can it be programmatically join ? If some properties via cursor is available, then I want it to join with my current piece. Else , it will return null.

> The main purpose is to not manually search/browse my piece. I need it to be *Auto join* / programmatically join without user need to browse the piece by themselves. If not , I have to enable sendmail to admin to tell that, "Your blog receives **Likes !** Join it to your blog piece now !" . Something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at how they do it here on self.beforeInsert:

https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-samples/commit/7f0b2b90377be4c4be216c8213ca4783ed2ec656

More info from the docs here on cursors:

https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/intermediate/cursors.html

Comment: Ohh , now I get it how does that code works. In collection , I saw that pieceIds available in database but I didn't get the whole picture of it. Thanks Oli Kasicki ! :)